# Split a string that has pockets of back-tick strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, split

Is there a way in javascript I can split a string that has back-ticks in them? Here is an example

```
'abcf `foo` asdjhash..`bar`.'
```

turns into

```
['abcf','foo','asdjhash..', 'bar','.']
```

The following seems to do it - a.split('`') but I need a way to find out after the fact that 'foo' and 'bar' were actually back-ticked so that I can treat them separately after, while looping through the split entries and processing them. (and make sure the split is reliable as well)

Thank you

Comment: Are words space seperated

Comment: how are the words separated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just see if the index of the element is odd:

```
'abcf `foo` asdjhash..`bar`.'.split('`').map((el, i) => i % 2 ? '`' + el + '`' : el)

// ["abcf ", "`foo`", " asdjhash..", "`bar`", "."]
```